What does it mean by Continous Current Control for a 24 Volts AC solenoid?
I have BERMAD irrigation 24V AC solenoid series S-390-3-D. Link has been attached of the product.https://www.bermad.com/app/uploads/IR_Accessories-Solenoid-S-390-3W_Product-Page_English.pdf. I would like to know here what does it mean by continuous current control? I have used TRIAC and DIAC based circuit to control this valve. My concern is for achieving continuous current control do we need PID based PWM control system here or simple GPIO ON/OFF would work here?

It is not obvious to me whether this is about a continuous current in water flow, or an electric current. There is no mention of a maximum electric current in the datasheet or I didn't find it.
In case you want to apply a continuous electric current to the device, you could use a low voltage switch mode controller like the classic MC34063.
The schematic below will create a continuous 50mA through the solenoid:

The V1, 24 input is 24V DC that could also be a rectified 24V AC.

In this context, "continuous current" refers to valves that return to an 'off' position when the power (typically 24VAC at mains frequency) is removed, as opposed to "latching" valves (which are typically 24VDC) that turn on and off with momentary pulses and otherwise retain their state).
The "continuous current" AC solenoid valve  represents an inductive load and typically has a current of < 1A. You could use a relay, a triac or a more complex circuit using back-to-back MOSFETs (or an SSR rated for 24VAC).
A relay or triac is probably the easiest and cheapest method. Commercial controllers like the below one use a BT136 triac. That is a fairly sensitive triac and can be driven directly from many MCU outputs (-10mA) if you avoid Quadrant IV (MT2-, G+). Typically MT1 is connected to +5 and the GPIO pulls the gate low through a resistor. I see two resistors and a spot for what was likely a ferrite bead replaced by a 0 ohm resistor. So maybe something like this:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Image from this video:

Of course you could always use an inexpensive sink driver chip such as a ULN2003/2803 to drive 7 or 8 triacs with much higher current if desired, and from just about any MCU output, including 3.3V.
It does not appear necessary to use a snubber with a 600V moderate sensitivity triac. Triacs typically dissipate around 1W per ampere of load current, so if you have many outputs conducting current simultaneously you may need to consider thermal design.
